# openxml sdk excel total sums

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

i am having difficulties with open xml sdk:
i am trying to generate excel file with several columns that have numbers and i want to have total sum at the end

i have tried to Generate Table Definition Part Content and inside define every column (id, name etC). If column has true for TotalColumn, it adds code (rough example)

```
var column = new TableColumn{
id = 1, 
name = "example", 
TotalsRowFunction = TotalsRowFunctionValues.Sum,
TotalsRowFormula = new TotalsRowFormula("=SUBTOTAL(109;[" + rowName + "])")
};
```

I can't get it to work, when i open excel it reports error, but it doesn't explicitly says what the problem is... I tried with microsoft validator but can't figure anything out...

I'd appreciate any help / example code since i can't google anything out

EDIT: 
i use this at the end:

```
workbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
workbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a cell formula?

E.g.

```
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
cell.CellFormula = new CellFormula(string.Format("=SUBTOTAL({0};[{1}])", "109", rowName));

//This will force a full recalculation of all the cells
workbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
workbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
```

Comment: this doesn't work as well :(
i still get error and nothing is being calculated in table

I forgot to mention that i use that recalculations as well so i'll update original question

on the other hand, this works: 
cell.CellFormula = new CellFormula("=SUM(I6:I8)");

but it isn't good enough for me since i need to filter table results as well and then update this value ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended using EPPlus for this as it seems to be working simple and efficient